# Grails .slcache is not getting recreated on a new build

Tags: grails

I'm running a Grails build.  For some reason, the .war file created sometimes does not get the appropriate .jar files loaded into the WEB-INF/lib folder. A subsequent Tomcat deployment fails. A co-worker that encountered this issue said to get rid of the .slcache in the user home folder on my windows server. I deleted the folder under c:/Users/myuser/.grails/.slcache.  I re-ran a build and the .slcache is not getting recreated and I am still missing the .jar files.

Any idea what is happening and how to resolve?

Comment: None of that makes any sense.  You say "the .war file created sometimes does not get the appropriate .jar files loaded into the WEB-INF/lib folder" and I am not sure what that means.  Are jars missing?  If so, which ones?  You say "A subsequent Tomcat deployment fails.".  How does it fail?  Are you using SpringLoaded in your deployment environment or are you talking about the development environment created by "grails run-app"?

Comment: You also said "I re-ran a build and the .slcache is not getting recreated and I am still missing the .jar files.".  It isn't clear what you mean by "re-ran a build".  If you mean building a .war file, the .slcache directory is not supposed to be created when building a .war file.  It is only created at runtime by SpringLoaded.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the .slcache file.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try changing the spark plugs (or at a minimum cleaning and re-gapping them) in your car? That'll be about as helpful.

The .slcache directory is created by spring-loaded, which Grails uses for class reloading when running the app with `grails run-app`. It has absolutely nothing to do with creating war files.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue.  As pointed out, the .slcache file has nothing to do with the packaging issue.  The second part of the answer was useful, the first part ...

Comment: Hours wasted searching for this. Thanks!